# jquery colorbox not loading iframe content

Tags: jquery, uploadify, colorbox

I am stuck at one point on my site:  http://clients.arkamatics.com/signature/ where I am using colorbox with some other plugins, like uploadify and colorpicker, the code works fine for me when I check it on my local xampp server, but once I uploaded it online the colorbox is not loading iframe and content, to follow you can perform the following step:

1. open the site: http://clients.arkamatics.com/signature/
2. on left bottom there is a upload button click on that and upload a file,
3. on upload complete process, an alert (which is part of our debug) will show you url we are passing to colorbox to open in iframe.
4. the colorbox opens but only shows a loading icon, doesn't load the url content in iframe, below is set of code I am using to do the same:

   ```
   $("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
   'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
   'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
   'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
   'folder': '/images',
   'multi': false,
   'displayData': 'speed',
   'auto'      : true,
   'buttonImg' : 'uploadify/btnupload.png',
   'wmode' : 'transparent',
   'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
       //alert('There are ' + fileObj.name + ' files remaining in the queue.'+fileObj.type);
       //$(".img_tpl").load('uploadedimage.php?filename='+fileObj.name);
       var filename = fileObj.name.replace(/ /g,"_"); 
       var colboxurl = 'upload1/uploadedimage.php?filename='+filename;
       alert(colboxurl);
       $.fn.colorbox({iframe: true, href:colboxurl, width:"90%", height:"90%",onClosed:function(){ 
                       $(".img_tpl").load('upload1/showfinalimage.php?filename='+filename,function(){   
                                                   $(".file_name").val($(".img_tpl img").attr('src'));
                                                   $(".remove_img").show();
                                                   adjustheights();
                                               })

       }});
   }
   });
   ```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some colorbox or Lightbox dosen't open as personally I have researched many plugins but none worked as they take as dynamic links while loading them.So better is to use the `jquery image gallery plugin` from here and everything works fine.

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-Image-Gallery/